# Child components re-rendering on parent re-render

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to react and I have been taking apart a web application and replacing parts with react components. I am now working on a component that holds a few of the different components that I created.

In the new component I make an API call in the componentDidMount function and create the children components. At first glance everything looks perfect, but when we make a state change in one of the child components then make a change in the parent component the children components reset their state to how they were before the changes.

I understand whats going on that the state isn't being passed to the parent, but I'm not sure if there a design for this that I am just missing or if I need to move to a redux store to make this work

```
class Frame extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       tab: "tab1",
       tab1: null,
       tab2: null,
   }
}
componentDidMount() {
   let data = this.props.service.getData();
   let tab1 = (<Tab1 {...data} />);
   let tab2 = (<Tab2 {...data} />);
   this.setState({tab1:tab1, tab2:tab2});
}

render(){
    if (!this.state.tab1 || !this.state.tab2){
         return (<div>Loading</div>)
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            <li onClick={()=>{this.setState({tab:"tab1"})}}></li>
            <li onClick={()=>{this.setState({tab:"tab2"})}}></li>
        <ul>
        <div>
               {this.state.tab === "tab1" &&
                    this.state.tab1
                }

                {this.state.tab === "tab2" &&
                    this.state.tab2
                }
         </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: You are unmounting the child component at each tab change, so their local state is lost. You should either always render the child component ( maybe just hide them) or keep their state in the parent component. Other point, it's probably better to just keep the data in your component instead of the rendered component

Comment: This worked. I just moved the if logic to hide them using a css class. so that they are rendered only once since the if logic isn't stopping the rendering of the other tabs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

axnyff, comment was the solution. The if would instantiate the object again in render since it wasn't there before. If I used a css class to hide them they will only be instantiated once since

```js
class Frame extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         tab: "tab1",
         tab1: null,
         tab2: null,
     }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
     let data = this.props.service.getData();
     let tab1 = (<Tab1 {...data} />);
     let tab2 = (<Tab2 {...data} />);
     this.setState({tab1:tab1, tab2:tab2});
  }

  render(){
      if (!this.state.tab1 || !this.state.tab2){
           return (<div>Loading</div>)
      }

      return (
          <ul>
              <li onClick={()=>{this.setState({tab:"tab1"})}}></li>
              <li onClick={()=>{this.setState({tab:"tab2"})}}></li>
          <ul>
          <div>
                 <div class=> {this.state.tab !== "tab1" && "hidden"}>
                      {this.state.tab1}
                 </div> 

                 <div class=> {this.state.tab !== "tab2" && "hidden"}>
                      {this.state.tab2}
                 </div>
           </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a click handler that sets state, and call it onClick rather than setting state directly in render.

Answer (score 0):

### You are using a little different . You should set the data . Also `componentDidMount` works only once.

```
class Frame extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  tab: 'tab1',
  data: null,
 };
}
componentDidMount() {
 let data = this.props.service.getData();
 if (data) {
   this.setState({ data });
 }
}

render() {
if (this.state.data) {
  return <div>Loading</div>;
}

return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ tab: 'tab1' });
        }}
      />
      <li
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ tab: 'tab2' });
        }}
      />
    </ul>
    <div>
      {this.state.tab === 'tab1' && <Tab {...this.state.data} />}
      {this.state.tab === 'tab2' && <Tab {...this.state.data} />}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
 }
```